# How to assign index or access index of time series objects?

Tags: r

My example.

Some data:

```
  set.seed(1000)
  dates<- seq.Date(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2013-01-31"),by='days')
  y <- round(3 * 3 + rnorm(31),1)
  df<- cbind.data.frame(dates, y)
```

Now I would like to access df in order to get the values of `y from "2013-01-25" to "2013-01-31"`:

```
  estimtaionPeriod <- as.Date(c("2013-01-25", "2013-01-31"))
  length.estimationPeriod.values <-df$dates[estimtaionPeriod[[1]] : estimtaionPeriod[[2]]]
```

But I get `NAs`. So I suppose I have to define a time series object:

```
  library(zoo)
  library(xts)


  ts <- ts(df$y, start=as.Date("2013-01-01"), end=as.Date("2013-01-31"))
  length.estimationPeriod.values <-ts[estimtaionPeriod[[1]] : estimtaionPeriod[[2]]]


  ts <- zoo(df$y, order.by = as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2013-01-31"))
  length.estimationPeriod.values <-ts[estimtaionPeriod[[1]] : estimtaionPeriod[[2]]]
```

However, that was not successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) subset** Try subsetting `df` on the indicated condition:

```
subset(df, dates >= "2013-01-25" & dates <= "2013-01-31")
```

**2) window.zoo** Another possibility is to convert the series to zoo and use `window`:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(df)
w <- window(z, start = "2013-01-25", end = "2013-01-31")
fortify.zoo(w) # optional - to convert back to data.frame
```

**3) xts**  xts has a special indexing notation for this:

```
library(xts)
x <- as.xts(read.zoo(df))
w <- x["2013-01-25/2013-01-31"]
fortify.zoo(w) # optional - to convert back to data.frame
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach was very close.  One possible solution is to use the `which` function to find the indexes of the start and stop points.  For example:

```
estimtationPeriod <- as.Date(c("2013-01-25", "2013-01-31"))

startstop=match(estimtationPeriod , df$dates)
df$y[startstop[1] : startstop[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `seq` of `date` object and then use `match` to get the corresponsing `y` value

```
df$y[match(seq(as.Date("2013-01-25"), as.Date("2013-01-31"), "days"), df$dates)]

#[1]  8.4  9.6  7.2  9.3  9.6 10.2  8.8
```